# Mount internal hdd so as i can symlink my home subdirectories like downloads, documents to it

Tags: 20.04, partitioning, mount, home-directory, symbolic-link

I am trying to dual boot my machine. Machine has a 128gb ssd and 1TB HDD. I gave 100 gbs of HDD for Windows(As i use it rarely).
For ubuntu 20.04,(which i am installing. Not yet installed)
i am giving 60GB for root.
10GB for swap
54GB for home.
I want to know under which file system and what mount point should i mount my HDD(1TB rem 900gbs) so that later i can symlink my home's subdirectories i.e downloads, docs, music, etc to my HDD.
So as to ensure bigger storage space.
I want to know

1. Which partitioning scheme for the HDD i. Logical or physical
2. File system for my HDD partition eg Ext4, Ext3 or FAT32
3. Mount Point i should create for it(if anything in specific)

Note: I am currently installing and am not done installing yet.

Comment: Unless you have a special need for many partitions it is best to let the install make the necessary partitions. That way you do not run  out of space in any one.

Comment: Thanks @David. Okay but i have two drives and one is ssd. I want to install my home in ssd as well but then i will have limited space for large file. How to mount my HDD and under what file system so as to ensure i can symlink my home's subdirectories which would be in SSD to that HDD.

Comment: LInking data partiitons is a bit more advanced. But default install of just / (root) goes back to when drives were small and/or users were dual booting on same drive. I used D: drive partition in XP years ago. I made it a shared data partition and created an ext4 data partition. Some info if desired: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know under which file system and what mount point should i mount my HDD(1TB rem 900gbs) so that later i can symlink my home's subdirectories i.e downloads, docs, music, etc to my HDD.

It is fully your call. You decide upon that. Once it is mounted automatically during startup, you will be able to create symlinks to that storage.

There is even no strong convention on where to store such volume.

- You could mount it in a directory under `/media`. In that case, by default, the volume will be shown as an icon in the left pane of the file manager.
- You could mount it under your custom directory, e.g. `/data`.

To mount a partition stored on an internal disk automatically during startup, first create the desired mount point (i.e., the directory in which the contents of the partition will appear once mounted). Then you can use the utility "Disks" to configure the mount:

- Click the partition in the map, then the gear icon: select "Edit mount options").
- Uncheck the switch "User Session Defaults".
- Check "Mount at system startup", for "Mount Point" provide the full path name to your existing mount point (e.g. `/media/my_drive` or `/data/my_drive`).
- For "Filesystem Type", provide the filesystem used on the disk, e.g. `ext4` or `ntfs`. You can see the file system of your partitions in the output of `lsblk -f`.

Seasoned linux users typically will directly edit the configuration file `/etc/fstab` instead.